# Why are there so many people with 101 rep?

Tags: support, reputation

This seems like it may be a glitch or bug. If you look at the list of users and work your way down from the top (rep-wise), you'll find that everyone from page 61 to page 186 (of 333 pages) has 101 rep.

What's up with that? Based on the number of badges they've earned it looks like a bunch of noobs who got a hundred points for some reason.

Comment: That's right. Per freiheit's answer, they got 100 points for some reason :-)

Comment: What I find interesting is the number of new users we see who come from outside the SE network. I thinks that's very healthy for this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe most of those got 101 reputation points by these two things:

1. All users start with one reputation point.
2. You *associate accounts* of two or more Stack Exchange network sites, and at least one of those accounts already has 200 or more reputation: **+100** on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)

Copied from this complete explanation of rep here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/116207

That is, users with 101 reputation points are active elsewhere on the Stack Exchange network of sites, but haven't done any reputation gaining (or losing) activities on this particular site.